# Plot above desired region

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot a real-valued function $f$ of two real variables $x,y$ but only over the region of the $x$-$y$ plane satisfying
\begin{align}
  x>0, \qquad -x^{3/2} < y < x^{3/2}.
\end{align}
Is there a straightforward way to do this using Plot3D?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionFunction.html) option is what you're looking for:

```
Plot3D[Cos[x] + Sin[y], {x, -1, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 RegionFunction -> (#1 > 0 && - #1^(3/2) < #2 < #1^(3/2) &)]
```

[image: plot]

The arguments provided to the function vary a bit depending on which plot function you are using, you can see under "Details" in the documentation. ("More Information" in older versions)

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The second iterator (for `y`) may depend on the first:

```
Plot3D[Cos[x] + Sin[y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, -x^(3/2), x^(3/2)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]