# How do I remove part of the plot?

Tags: plotting, regions, piecewise

I am in a similar situation as the one described in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154134/8822): I need to `Plot3D` a piecewise function with complicated inequality restriction. I am using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154139/8822) since the other one makes Mathematica hang. It works (even though it is very slow in my case), but it plots also the plane `z=0` in some regions: how can I remove it?

I report the code of the answer:

```
A=(2.29-2.6*s-2*s^2+2.2 s^3 +c*(-1 + s) (-1.3 + 1.1*s^2))/(4.58 - 5.2*s - 4 s^2 + 4.4*s^3);
Plot3D[A*Boole[-0.665954 < s < 
 0.826905 && ((-1.1 + s^2) (-0.01 + 2 (-1 + s)^2 (1 + s) + 
      0.1 (3 - 6 s + 2 s^3)))/(0.01 (7 + s - 
       s^2 (3 + s)) + (-1 + s^2)^2 (-7 + s (-1 + 4 s)) + 
    0.1 (1 + s) (-8 + s (16 + s (9 + s (2 + s) (-9 + 4 s)))))
 < c <= -(((-1 + s) (-0.01 + 2 (-1 + s)^2 (1 + s) + 
        0.1 (3 - 6 s + 2 s^3)))/(-0.02 + (-1 + s)^2 (1 + s) (3 + 
         s) + 0.1 (3 + s (-6 + s (-2 + s (2 + s))))))], {s, -1, 
 1}, {c, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Comment: Add `RegionFunction -> (#3 > 0&)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd put the `condition` in `Boole[condition]` into a `RegionFunction`:

```
A = (2.29 - 2.6*s - 2*s^2 + 2.2 s^3 + 
     c*(-1 + s) (-1.3 + 1.1*s^2))/(4.58 - 5.2*s - 4 s^2 + 4.4*s^3);
Plot3D[A, {s, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{s, c, a}, 
   Identity[-0.665954 < s < 
      0.826905 && ((-1.1 + s^2) (-0.01 + 2 (-1 + s)^2 (1 + s) + 
           0.1 (3 - 6 s + 2 s^3)))/(0.01 (7 + s - 
            s^2 (3 + s)) + (-1 + s^2)^2 (-7 + s (-1 + 4 s)) + 
         0.1 (1 + s) (-8 + s (16 + s (9 + s (2 + s) (-9 + 4 s))))) < 
      c <= -(((-1 + s) (-0.01 + 2 (-1 + s)^2 (1 + s) + 
             0.1 (3 - 6 s + 2 s^3)))/(-0.02 + (-1 + s)^2 (1 + s) (3 + 
              s) + 0.1 (3 + s (-6 + s (-2 + s (2 + s))))))]]]
```

[image]

Then you don't need so high a setting for `PlotPoints`, which sppeds up the computation.