# How to remove part of the solution in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I am interested in plotting solutions to the equation $\lambda^2\sin^2(\alpha)-\sin^2(\lambda\alpha)=0$ with $\lambda>0$ and $0\le\alpha\le2\pi$. However, I am not interested in the trivial solution $\lambda=1$, Using

```
ContourPlot[l^2*Sin[a]^2-Sin[l*a]^2==0,{a,0,2*Pi},{l,0,5},PlotPoints->500]
```

yields the plot

[image: plot]

How do I remove that line at `l=1`? Similar questions like [How do I remove part of the plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211461/how-do-i-remove-part-of-the-plot) suggest using `RegionFunction`. However this doesn't seem to work for me. Presumably because the condition on `l` is not an inequality, but rather just removing one value.

**Edit:**

After some very helpful comments from @bmf I managed to get something that excludes the line $\lambda=1$, but includes the non-trivial solutions. Its not overly elegant but I consider a first order taylor series of $\frac{\lambda^2\sin^2(\alpha)-\sin^2(\lambda\alpha)}{\lambda-1}$ about $\lambda=1$ and include its zeroes in the plot for $1-\epsilon<\lambda<1+\epsilon$.

That is, I define

```
taylor[a_, l_, eps_] := 
If
[
    1 - eps < l < 1 + eps, 
    (-2 a Cos[a] Sin[a] + 2 Sin[a]^2) + (-a^2 Cos[a]^2 + Sin[a]^2 + a^2 Sin[a]^2) (l - 1),
    1
]
```

and write

```
p0 = ContourPlot[l^2*Sin[a]^2 - Sin[l*a]^2 == 0, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {l, 0, 5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, Exclusions -> {l == 1}, ContourStyle -> Blue];

p1 = ContourPlot[taylor[a, l, 0.02] == 0, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {l, 0, 5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, ContourStyle -> Blue];

Show[p0, p1]
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html)

```
ContourPlot[l^2*Sin[a]^2 - Sin[l*a]^2 == 0, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {l, 0, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 500, Exclusions -> {l == 1}]
```

> [image: plot]

**Edit: addressing the comment.**

This is not elegan, it's a very simple minded approach to the task, but it gives something that seems acceptable. At least as a first step.

```
p0 = ContourPlot[
   l^2*Sin[a]^2 - Sin[l*a]^2 == 0, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {l, 0, 5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 500, Exclusions -> {l == 1}, ContourStyle -> Blue];

p1 = ContourPlot[
   l^2*Sin[a]^2 - Sin[l*a]^2 == 0, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {l, 0, 5}, 
   RegionFunction -> (#1 >= 4 &), ContourStyle -> Blue];

p2 = ContourPlot[
   l^2*Sin[a]^2 - Sin[l*a]^2 == 0, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {l, 0, 5}, 
   RegionFunction -> (#1 >= 3.117 &), ContourStyle -> Blue];

Show[p0, p1, p2]
```

> [image: finalshow]

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be a straightforward answer.

Comment: @epiliam glad I was able to help :-)

Comment: this might be more difficult, but is there a way to include the $\lambda=1$ solution when its non-trivial. i.e. to remove the gaps on the curve?

Comment: sorry, just to make sure I understand properly. By gaps you mean the two white points on the plot with the `Exclusions` yes? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: The non-trivial solutions with $\lambda=1$ occur at $\tan (\alpha)=\alpha$ and at $\alpha=n \pi$ if that helps.

Comment: @epiliam thanks for the comments. Are you sure that it is $\tan(\alpha)=\alpha$? I am asking becasue I cannot see it. If I set $\lambda=1$ the equation trivializes

Comment: To remove the trivial $\lambda=1$ solution, consider $\frac{\lambda^2\sin^2(\alpha)-\sin^2(\lambda\alpha)}{\lambda-1}=0$. Use L'Hospital to compute limit as $\lambda\to 1$ and you find there still exists solutions when $\sin^2(\alpha)-\alpha\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: Its all good if you cannot include the points. The plot is way better as is.

Comment: @epiliam thanks. I will try to work something and let you know if I succeed :)

Comment: @epiliam I just added something that uses `RegionFunction`. It's not an optimal approach, but I hope that you can play a bit around with it and after some experimentation you'll get the desired output.

Comment: thanks for that. It still produces a line at $\lambda=1$ though, which is not what I wanted but rather to just fill in the gaps on the curves which occur at $\alpha=\pi$ and at the smallest positive root of $\tan(\alpha)-\alpha$ $(\alpha\approx4.49)$. However, I appreciate the effort and it gives me some thoughts to come up with a solution.

Comment: @epiliam yes I understand what you say. Well, the point would be to manipulate the `RegionFunction` in such a way that you get a single point from one and a single point from the other. This is what I tried to demonstrate. Note, also, that you can constrain the `RegionPlot` with something like `(#1 >= 3.117 || #2 >= 4.117 &)` or similar statements. Not very elegant, I know. Sorry

Comment: thanks heaps for your help. I managed to get something that worked and included it in the original question for those that are interested.

Comment: @epiliam Wonderful stuff. Thanks for letting me know :-)

Answer (score 5):

We can plot `{l, 1, 5}` and `{l, 0, 1}` respectively.

```
plot1 = ContourPlot[
   l^2*Sin[a]^2 - Sin[l*a]^2 == 0, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {l, 1, 5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4];
plot2 = ContourPlot[
   l^2*Sin[a]^2 - Sin[l*a]^2 == 0, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {l, 0, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4];
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's much nicer then the way I did it, and more robust for large $\alpha$ if I were interested in that..

Answer (score -1):

I often face this problem. My solution is not elegant, but effective. Export the plot to Powerpoint, and past a white borderless patch over the bits you dont want. This should give you a serviceable pdf.

Comment: At times, when there aren't many choices, an external software can be used as a solution/workaround achieve goals. In this case, however, it is not necessary. Please look at the other answers.